# Mail command sending the error log file as attachment instead of in the Body in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, mailx

I'm having an issue while sending an email from the Linux box using mail command. Instead of sending the error log as in the Body it is sending as an attachment in .bin format. Where as in few instances it is sending in the Body. Below is the log details which I'm trying to send via email as body. Is it because of Special characters like "/" in the log it is sending as .bin attachemnt. I can use sendmail inorder to fix this but we want to send it using mail command.

Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/DBSInboundandOutbound/prod/outbound/DSP/PartsMaster/PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_20211015071711.xml.gz.tmp' while uploading the file Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename '/DBSInboundandOutbound/prod/outbound/DSP/PartsMaster/PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_20211015071711.xml.gz.tmp' to /DBSInboundandOutbound/prod/outbound/DSP/PartsMaster/PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_20211015071711.xml.gz'. Server replied with: 550 'PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_20211015071711.xml.gz.tmp': cannot rename.
2021-10-15 02:01:49,342 ERROR | dbs-intg-scheduler-18 | c.n.d.j.adapter.support.MDCFatalErrorChannelInterceptor | [DBS] Fatal Error [org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [/datapp/common/batch_datafile/parts/P-16/outComingFolder/PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_20211015071711.xml.gz]] -org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/DBSInboundandOutbound/prod/outbound/DSP/PartsMaster/PartsMasterFull_NNANissanV5124_2021101507171
1.xml.gz.tmp' while uploading the file

```
mContent=`cat $1`
msgimp=$2
mailsub=$3
monitor=$4
logname=$5
echo  >> /datapp/common/operation_admin/monitor/monitor_log/$mailsub.txt
echo $mContent  >> /datapp/common/operation_admin/monitor/monitor_log/$mailsub.txt


mail -s "[Prod] [$monitor] [$msgimp] [$mailsub] found in $logname log" -r "DBS Production 
Alert <noreply@*******.com>" alert.*********.com < 
/datapp/common/operation_admin/monitor/monitor_log/$mailsub.txt

rm -f /datapp/common/operation_admin/monitor/monitor_log/$mailsub.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using the `$mContent` variable? Just use `cat "$1" >> filename`

Comment: Remember to quote all your variables.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
mContent=`cat $1`
...
echo $mContent  >> /datapp/common/operation_admin/monitor/monitor_log/$mailsub.txt
```

At this point, the contents of `$mailsub.txt` are **not the same** as the contents of `$1`. The mContent variable is **unquoted**, therefore all sequences of whitespace (including newlines!) get replaced by a single space. So the body of the email is one long line.

I'm guessing here, but if that line is very long, I can imagine some part of the email system would change the message to move the body into an attachment.

I don't see why it would be necessary to read the input file, write it (incorrectly) to a new file, mail the contents of the new file, and delete the new file. Try this instead:

```sh
mData=$1
subject=$(printf "[Prod] [%s] [%s] [%s] found in %s log" "$4" "$2" "$3" "$5")
from="DBS Production Alert <noreply@*******.com>"
to="alert.*********.com"

mail -s "$subject" -r "$from" "$to" < "$mData"
```

Comment: I realized that as soon as I submitted.